# How to iterate Json type in jquery

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

I would like to know about extracting value from json node in jquery. following is the code which i used

```
$.ajax({
             type : 'POST',
             url : '@routes.Application.searchItemcodes()',
             data : {
                 boxnumber : $(this).text(),    
                 orgname   : 'I099'                 
             },
             success : function(jsonp) {

                 $.each(jsonp, function(i, item) {
                     console.log(item[0]);

                 });

             },
             error : function() {

                 alert("Error IN UP")
             }

             });
```

following result is I am getting in console.

```
Object `{itemcode: "8225612", modelname: "M LIGHT ", quantity: 1}`
```

if I print jsonp i am getting following result in console.

```
Object {data: Array[3], status: "Success"}
```

I need to iterate Array[3]. The same has itemcode,modelname and quantity field.for example

```
data: Array[3]: 
Object1:{itemcode: "8225612", modelname: "M LIGHT ", quantity: 1}
Object2:{itemcode: "8225613", modelname: "M Green ", quantity: 2}
Object3:{itemcode: "8225613", modelname: "M LIGHT ", quantity: 3}
```

Please any one help me to extract these three objects one by one based on itemcode ,modelcode and quantity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
array = jsonp.data;
for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
  console.log(array[i]);
}
```

Comment: its working but I have to specify array[i].itemcode, array[i].modelname,array[i].quantity. then it is giving desired output. heart full thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

try this ...
As you collection is inside the **data key** try the following.

```
success : function(jsonp) {

                 $.each(jsonp.data, function(i, item) {
                     console.log(item);

                 });

             },
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: its coming as undefined